# FastAPI gives error with sqlalchemy data model due to Pydantic check failing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi, pydantic

I am writing a small webapplication with FastAPI v0.103.1 and sqlalchemy v2.0.21. When I run the code, I get a FAstAPIError:

`fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'app.models.Post'> is a valid Pydantic field type. If you are using a return type annotation that is not a valid Pydantic field (e.g. Union[Response, dict, None]) you can disable generating the response model from the type annotation with the path operation decorator parameter response_model=None. Read more: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/`

My database.py:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/fastapi"

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

models.py:

```py
from .database import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, TIMESTAMP, text


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    title = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    content = Column(String(500), nullable=False)
    published = Column(Boolean, server_default="TRUE", nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(
        TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=text("now()")
    )
```

app.py:

```py
@app.post("/posts", response_model=List[schemas.Post])
def create_posts(post: models.Post, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    ## ORM implementation (without SQL)
    new_post = models.Post(**post.model_dump())
    db.add(new_post)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_post)

    return {"data": new_post}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I added the request_model in the route: `@app.post("/posts", response_model=List[schemas.Post])`

I added a schemas.py with the same Pydantic model:

```py
from datetime import date
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Post(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    content: str
    published: bool
    created_at: date

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Both steps did not solve the issue.

Comment: You're still using your SQLAlchemy model as input argument, switch `post: models.Post` to `post: schemas.Post`.